# Ubuntu 20.04 Unity - Split screen into 4

Tags: unity, display

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 with Unity desktop environment.

I would like to split my (big) second screen into 4 different virtual screens, into a grid of virtual screens. I do not know how to do this. Unity tweak tool is already installed, but that did not offer this option.